# Unresolvable dependency resolving

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have the following code in my routes.php project.

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct($name) {
    }
}

$app->get('/', function () {
    return "Ola, mundo! :)";
});

$app->group(['middleware' => 'authAPI', 'prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->post('v1/payment/create', function(Foo $api){
        dd($api);
    });
});
```

When I try to access my /api/v1/payment/create this gives me the error:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $name ]] in class Foo
```

Obviously I'm not passing any value to $name. My question is how to do it, the most laravelish and correct way possible.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding

Comment: Been there but I can't understand how to apply to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a binding to the IOC container.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding

In Lumen, `$app` is an instance of the container, so you can perform the binding in the same file as follows:

```
class Foo
{

    public function __construct($name)
    {

    }
}

$app->bind(Foo::class, function($app){
    return new Foo('David');
});

$app->get('/', function () {
    return "Ola, mundo! :)";
});

$app->group(['middleware' => 'authAPI', 'prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->post('v1/payment/create', function(Foo $api){
        dd($api);
    });
});
```

Probably you want to do this in a service provider, but as your example code has a class defined inline, i thought this the simplest way to describe the solution

Edit to address the situation whereby the `$name` parameter changes a lot, there are a few ways to handle it.

Ditch IOC and just create the Foo instance in the route closure:

```
$app->get('blah', function(){
    $foo = new Foo('blahblah');
});
$app->get('splarg', function(){
    $foo = new Foo('blobblob');
});
```

Alter `Foo` and add a `setName` method:

```
class Foo
{
    private $name;
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

$app->get('blah', function(Foo $foo){
    $foo->setName('blahblah');
});
$app->get('splarg', function(Foo $foo){
    $foo->setName('blobblob');
});
```

Create a `FooFactory` and inject that:

```
Class FooFactory
{
    public function createFoo($name)
    {
        return new Foo($name);
    }
}

$app->get('blah', function(FooFactory $factory){
    $foo = $factory->createFoo('blahblah');
});
$app->get('splarg', function(FooFactory $factory){
    $foo = $factory->createFoo('blobblob');
});
```

Comment: Works just the way I wanted! I couldn't figure it out just looking at the docs. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad i could help you

Comment: Is there a way to bind inside the $app->post()?

Comment: Not really, that breaks to whole idea of Inversion Of Control. If you need to define a specific `$name` for each route, you need to refactor. Either just create the `Foo` instance within the route closure (quick, but breaks IOC principle), alter `Foo` to have a `setName()` method, or create a `FooFactory` that takes the name and returns a new `Foo` instance, then inject that instead

Comment: I made an edit to explain my comment a little better